# Should you always set the AJAX request to TRUE for async?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, request

Some minor question(just interested), in every AJAX request docs they set it to true(async).
Example:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //some code here
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

But the JavaScrips is asynchronous language plus onreadystatechange already means that the request is async and here is the question, should you always specify "true" and why?
P.S Maybe there is something minor happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. Synchronous AJAX blocks the UI and is deprecated, you should not use it.

Note that the default is `true`, so you can just leave that argument out. You only need to provide it explicitly if you have to use additional arguments after it.